# How to decode JeroMQ byte array in PyZMQ?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq, jeromq

I am trying to hook up a JeroMQ publisher to a PyZMQ subscriber. It works well but I don't know how to decode/deserialize the data I am getting on the Python side.

For example, here is a byte array that I am sending from Java: `[10, 10, 7, 55, 79]`. My goal would be to recover the same array of integers in Python. In practice, I am getting this here `b"\n\n\xf97O"` on the Python end. I was hoping that a `bytes.decode("utf-8")` would maybe get me something like `101075579`, but apparently utf-8 is the wrong codec. Do you know what kind of object `b"\n\n\xf97O"` is?

Here is the code I am using:

**Java side**

```java
ZContext context = new ZContext();
ZMQ.Socket broadcastSocket = context.createSocket(ZMQ.PUB);
broadcastSocket.bind("tcp://*:55555");

byte[] payload = new byte[] {10, 10, 7, 55, 79};
broadcastSocket.send(payload);
```

**Python side**

```py
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket = setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:55555")


while 1:
    message = socket.recv()
    print(message) # outputs b"\n\n\xf97O"
```

Do you have an idea of how to solve this problem? Note that `ZMQ.Socket.sendMore(String)` sends objects that do get recognized by Python as strings of bytes but I am not sure how to properly parse them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to decode anything, for example: `print(message[0], message[1])`. The data is raw bytes only that "print" does some simple things like print them as ASCII but that is only superficial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object, also called a byte-string. If you just convert it to a list, you get a list of integers, one per byte:

```
>>> list(b"\n\n\xf97O")
[10, 10, 249, 55, 79]
```

and you can also subscript and iterate over it directly without even using `list`, e.g. `message[4]` will be 79.

(I'm not sure about the discrepancy between 7 and 249, but I'm guessing you miscopied something on your end, or used data from two different runs).

Comment: Awesome, thanks hobbs :)! Yup it should've been 249.